# AWS .NET SDK works for DynamoDB, not S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-sdk, localstack

I am running a .NET Core Web API app, where I initialize DynamoDB and S3 with localstack endpoints:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAmazonDynamoDB>(sp =>
{
      var clientConfig = new AmazonDynamoDBConfig { ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4569" };
      return new AmazonDynamoDBClient(clientConfig);
});
services.AddSingleton<IAmazonS3>(sp =>
{
       var clientConfig = new AmazonS3Config { ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4572" };
       return new AmazonS3Client(clientConfig);
});
```

I've started DynamoDB and S3 services at localstack. When I attempt to use the services (via IAmazonDynamoDB and IAmazonS3 clients respectfully) DynamoDB works like a charm while S3 throws *"nodename nor servname provided, or not known"* exception. Any idea what is wrong?

I am running localstack from the latest docker image, if that could be related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out [here](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/942#issuecomment-427327889)  that `ForcePathStyle = true` has to be added

So basically for S3 config that works:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAmazonS3>(sp =>
{
   var clientConfig = 
       new AmazonS3Config { ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4572", ForcePathStyle = true };
   return new AmazonS3Client(clientConfig);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across this question in the future and are looking for a more streamlined way to integrate .NET applications with LocalStack:

Consider using [LocalStack.NET](https://github.com/localstack-dotnet/localstack-dotnet-client). It's a thin wrapper around the AWS SDK.NET designed to automatically configure the target endpoints to use LocalStack. This can help avoid potential misconfigurations and simplify the setup process.

With LocalStack.NET, you can set up your services like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddLocalStack(Configuration);
    services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
    services.AddAwsService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
    services.AddAwsService<IAmazonS3>();
}
```

This approach ensures that the correct endpoints are set for each service, reducing the chances of encountering issues like the one described in the original question.

For a more detailed guide on how to get started with LocalStack.NET, you can take a look at the [Getting Started](https://github.com/localstack-dotnet/localstack-dotnet-client/wiki/Getting-Started) documentation.

I hope this helps readers looking to integrate .NET with LocalStack!